# Optimization using package "nloptr"

Tags: r, optimization

I am trying to replicate results in R from Excel's "Solver" add-in. I don't know about the inner workings of optimization (mathematically), hence my confusion at most post results as well as the error messages I am receiving. I tried using the `optimx` package, but apparently that doesn't allow for too much control over the constraints in the optimization, so now I'm trying out the `nloptr` package.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is replicate an optimum portfolio calculation (financial). Below is a sample of my code:

```
ret.cov <- cov(as.matrix(ret.p[,1:30]))
wts <- rep(1/portfolioSize, times = portfolioSize)
sharpe <- function(wts) {
  mean.p <- sum(colMeans(ret.p[,1:30])*wts)
  var.p <- t(wts) %*% (ret.cov %*% (wts))
  sd.p <- sqrt(var.p)
  SR <- (mean.p - Rf)/sd.p
  return(as.numeric(SR))
}
fun.eq <- function(wts) {
  sum(wts) == 1
}

optim.p <- nloptr(x0 = wts, eval_f = sharpe, lb = 0, ub = 1, eval_g_eq = fun.eq)

sharpe(as.numeric(optim.p$solution))
```

1. Calculates the covariance matrix of 30 stocks and their returns
2. Initializes the weights of those stocks to optimize (equally weighted to start)
3. Sets up a function to maximize which calculates the portfolio's Sharpe Ratio
4. Tries (???) to specify the equality function for `nloptr` that states that the sum of the `wts` vector must be equal to 1.
5. Tries to maximize the function (though I think it's minimizing by default, and I don't know how to change that to maximize instead).
6. Checks the resulting, maximized Sharpe Ratio

The Sharpe calculation function works fine, when I try it outside of the `nloptr` function. The issues are various, from needing to specify the proper algorithm to use, to the function not accepting the equality function I supplied.

So, the questions I have are:

1. How do you change the `nloptr` to maximize instead of minimize?
2. How would one write an equality function to specify that the sum of the input vector (weights) must be equal to 1?
3. What is the proper algorithm to specify using `opts = list()` here? Excel uses something called "GRG Nonlinear".

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Hope it's still relevant...
You don't supply data so I can't run it but I'll try to help.

1) In order to maximize just minimize the -sharpe 
2) eval_g_eq needs to be in format of h(x)=0, meaning that you need on fun.eq to change `sum(wts) == 1` to `sum(wts) - 1`. 
3) There are a lot of decent options. I use NLOPT_LN_COBYLA

Comment: thanks for the reply! I've actually moved on to another (reproducible) issue of the same type, and if you could take a look at it, as well, I would appreciate it! Found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34796173/no-change-to-initial-values-using-nloptr-in-r