# No change to initial values using nloptr in R

Tags: r, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I've been struggling with optimization problems in R for months now. I've finally figured out `lpSolve` for linear problems, thanks to examples on data for fantasy sports. However, my original and (still) current problem is trying nonlinear optimization with equality constraints using `nloptr` in R.

What I'm trying to do is minimize the variance of a two-stock portfolio, in which the two stocks' returns are almost perfectly negatively correlated (for those that are familiar with academic finance, the end goal is to prove/disprove whether or not arbitrage opportunities exist). I want to minimize the variance, subject to the sum of the two weights being exactly equal to 1, while being between 0 and 1. Below is the exact code I am using, which should be easily reproducible:

```
sd1 <- 0.01
sd2 <- 0.025
corr.lo <- -0.999

# Objective function
eval.f <- function(w) {
  return(
    (w[1]*sd1)^2 +
      (w[2]*sd2)^2 +
      (2*w[1]*w[2]*sd1*sd2*corr.lo)
  )
}

# Constraint function
eval.g <- function(w) {
  return(w[1] + w[2] - 1)
}

w0 <- c(0.5, 0.5)

opts <- list('algorithm' = 'NLOPT_GN_ISRES', 'xtol_rel' = 1.0e-8)

res <- nloptr(
  x0 = w0,
  eval_f = eval.f,
  lb = c(0,0),
  ub = c(1,1),
  eval_g_eq = eval.g,
  opts = opts
)
```

The optimization runs without errors, and generates the following:

```
> res

Call:
nloptr(x0 = w0, eval_f = eval.f, lb = c(0, 0), ub = c(1, 1),     eval_g_eq = eval.g, opts = opts)


Minimization using NLopt version 2.4.0 

NLopt solver status: 5 ( NLOPT_MAXEVAL_REACHED: Optimization stopped because maxeval (above) was reached. )

Number of Iterations....: 100 
Termination conditions:  xtol_rel: 1e-08 
Number of inequality constraints:  0 
Number of equality constraints:    1 
Current value of objective function:  0.000125508655202602 
Current value of controls: 0.5 0.5
```

I'm using the above algorithm because that's one that runs without telling me I need a gradient (which I am not familiar with). The problem is, the initial values of `w0` DO NOT change from 50% each. Can anyone either reproduce this and offer advice, or try and point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

I've found the answer my own question. The optimization wasn't running long enough, I think. By specifying `maxeval = 1000000` in the `opts` list, I got an answer that satisfied the constraints.

Comment: @Modi , @Ryan Price, I had the same issue and just tried your solution and set `maxeval = 1000000`. I've been trying for almost 24h. I had increased the `maxeval` but not to your level and didn't get any difference. Somehow above a certain level it starts to work. Thank you for posting this question. Took me a while to find the answer.

Comment: I am also studying performance. I am using `nloptr` for that reason. In my case `Rsolnp::solnp` is taking 300 ms, which is really high. I need to bring it to less than 10ms. (not sure I can in R, but I least I can investigate which algo to use)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a that `nloptr` is sensitive to both, having `maxeval` be too low **and too high**.
I usually set my `maxeval = 1e7`. Works in 95% of cases.

In case `nloptr` is returning the initial guess, mess around with its `opts`, and it usually works.
However, if anyone knows of a reliable way to catch this error, let me know...